# PHP Content Type Mime and HTML tags

Tags: php, html, tags, content-type, mime

I'm using PHP and sending a header with Content-type:mime so I can print an image on the navigator with readfile command.

My question is: Is there a way to add html on the window that displays the image? I want to add a title and a favicon on the tab window where the image is read and displayed.

As soon as I add html code everything stops working.

This is my code:

```
$ImageRoute = "images/photo.png";
$MyImage = getimagesize($ImageRoute);
header("Content-type: {$MyImage['mime']}");
readfile($ImageRoute);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You might achieve this using an iframe. I haven't tried it, but off the top of my head this should work. When you read file, you are basically generating a file so you can't do anything inside that in the way of HTML.

Comment: @Rasclatt still not working by adding iframe. I think It's because of the type of header I'm sending: header("Content-type: {$MyImage['mime']}");

This might tell the navigator how to treat and display the document and since I'm not sending an HTML type of document, I think this is why I can't use html tags, but still I'm not sure If I'm correct.